# Use post_type in admin_menu action callback with wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I access `post_type` in the callback function for `admin_menu` action?

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_post_thumb_meta_box' );
function remove_post_thumb_meta_box()
{

    global $pagenow, $_wp_theme_features;
    if ( in_array( $pagenow,array('post.php','post-new.php')))
    {
        unset( $_wp_theme_features['post-thumbnails']);
    }
}
```

I need to hide `featured image metabox` only for post_type `location`.

Comment: Solved this by removing thumbnail from supports array at the time of post_type registration ``'supports' => array('title','custom-fields')``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:-

Add following line into your `theme's functions.php` file:-

```
remove_post_type_support( 'location', 'thumbnail' );
```

This will only effect your `location` post type.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`remove_meta_box( $id, $page, $context );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) function to remove the meta box. You can go and have a look at the parameters in the link I've provided

To better safe than sorry, hook your function to the [`add_meta_boxes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes) hook

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
 if (is_admin()) {
  remove_meta_box('postimagediv', 'location', 'normal');
 }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes', 999 );
```

Comment: This one not working, that's why tried the above code!

Comment: What is not working. Updated my answer. Forgot about priority. Should work now

Comment: Ok, I will check this later.

Comment: Solved this by removing thumbnail from supports array at the time of post_type registration ``'supports' => array('title','custom-fields')``